# How do I change the default 'remind before' time in calander?

Tags: 8.0, settings, calendars, reminders

How do I change the default reminder time (remind me before eg: 18 hours) in the calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that it's not possible to change the default reminder for calendar events in WP8 "Calendar".

You can find an entry about it in the feature suggestions website for WP, [here](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2500273-add-setting-to-turn-off-default-calendar-reminders).

An alternative would be to use another calendar application.