# How to change calendar birthday reminder timing on Windows phone 8.1?

Tags: 8.1, settings, calendars, outlook, nokia-lumia-820

I am getting Birthday reminder at 12 PM noon, Birthdays are loaded in my outlook calendar from google contacts and my Facebook contacts.

So **How to change this 12 PM timing to somewhat early around like 8 AM ?.**

I am using windows phone 8.1 OS

Comment: As of I know and I checked, it's not possible to set even in Windows Phone 10 Calendar also. You may check this out. http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2960/how-do-i-change-the-default-remind-before-time-in-calander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently not possible in the Calendar app.